# Spark Decision Tree on Java can't resolve trainClassifier method

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

So I'm using code like:

```
DecisionTree.trainClassifier((org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<LabeledPoint>)dtTraining, numClasses.intValue(), (java.util.Map<Integer,Integer>) categoricalFeaturesInfo,
                    impurity, maxDepth.intValue(), maxBins.intValue());
```

But having compilation error:

```
[ERROR] method org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree.trainClassifier(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint>,int,scala.collection.immutable.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,int,int) is not applicable
[ERROR] (argument mismatch; org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint>)
```

So the compiler doesn't see the valid method in DecisionTree.

In my pom.xml I'm having:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmml-model</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I'm looking into multiple examples of DecisionTree usage and it seems like everywhere everything is working ok. What could be the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Find out that I've accidently imported:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.LabeledPoint
```

Instead of:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
```